# Hardware NSS signal conficts with PA15 mapped with GPIO output

Tags: stm32, spi, cubemx

I'm having a Chinese development board of STM32F103RCT6 STM32_Mini_Pro where a winbond SPI flash is attached with SPI3. The Chip Select is attached with PA15 pin.

While configuring SPI in STM32 cubeMX, I assign Chip Select i.e. PA15 as GPIO output for software NSS.

But while assigning it i get an error like this

[image: Hardware NSS signal conflicts with PA15 mapped with GPIO output]

This is my assignment in Cube MX

[image: PA15 assigned as GPIO Output]

What is the reason for this problem and how to rectify it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem. Cube shows you that you can not assign slave select signal to PA15 (yes, it's rigth, you already mapped this pin as GPIO).
Hardware slave select it STM32 micros has the meaning only if you use MCU as slave device.

Comment: So i can use that pin as CS and continue??

Comment: Of course. You can use this pin as conventional GPIO output, pull it down at begin of transer and pull up after last byte.